# A coluna dt_movimentação terá o valor padrão a data do sistema

Tags: sql, oracle

tenho um script em oracle que dentro de uma tabela chamada "movimentaçao" existe uma coluna chamada "dt_movimentaçao" e dentro dessa coluna existe o valor DATE 
eu gostaria de mudar esse valor para a data do sistema com o alter table mais nao consigo

estou usando

ALTER TABLE tb_movimentaçao
modify (dt_movimentaçao SYSDATE) E NAO FUNCIONA

alguem sabe como resolvo esse poblema

Comment: Tente: `ALTER TABLE tb_movimentaçao MODIFY (dt_movimentaçao DEFAULT SYSDATE)`, a partir daí os registros incluídos na tabela passarão a conter a data do sistema do momento da inclusão. Se não for isso o que deseja explique melhor.

Comment: DATE é um type , um tipo de dado. SYSDATE é um operador que retorna a data e hora corrente do Servidor.